# Problem with the lookup in a Map to get the value of a stored variable

Tags: kframework

I am facing an issue when I try to do a lookup to get the value of a variable stored in an `env` configuration which is a `Map` (common pattern). Here is the extracted code why the syntax and the rewriting rule that create the issue:

```
syntax Exp
       ::= Id
     | Value
     | "read" "(" Exp ")"

syntax Value
       ::= ...
         | #loc(Int)

rule <k> read ( X:Id ) => read ( #loc( L )  ) ... </k>
     <env> ... X |-> L ... </env>
```

When I krun a little program, it become stuck in this configuration:

```
 <k>
    read ( x ) ~> #freezer_;_OSL-SYNTAX_Stmt_Exp0_ ( ) ~> .Stmts ~> .
 </k>
 <env>
    x |-> 0
    y |-> 2
 </env>
```

I expect that `read(x)` will be rewriting in `read(#loc(0))`, but the rule is not applied. If I comment the `env` configuration requirement in the rule and replace  `L` by  the constant `0`, the rule can be apply:

```
rule <k> read ( X:Id ) => read ( #loc( 0 )  ) ... </k>
//     <env> ... X |-> L ... </env>
```

And I got a termination `.` (because other rule will handle the `read(#loc(0))` after this one)

```
<k>
     .
</k>
<env>
     x |-> 0
     y |-> 2
</env>
```

I also tried to use this syntax from this documentation [here](https://kframework.org/k-distribution/include/kframework/builtin/domains/)

```
rule <k> read ( X:Id ) => read ( #loc( Env[X] )  ) ... </k>
     <env> Env:Map </env>
```

But I get a parsing error

```
[Error] Inner Parser: Parse error: unexpected token '['.
    Source(/home/alessio/Project/osl/model/./osl.k)
    Location(156,43,156,44)
```

Do you have an idea for debugging this?

Comment: Could you show us your configuration declaration please?

Comment: In general, you should provide (i) the version of K you're working with, and (ii) an _complete working_ minimal example, not a snippet.

In the second version of the rule, you would need to do `{Env[X]}:>Int`, which casts the map lookup to an `Int`, and fails (halts execution) if the lookup does not return an `Int`.